# Active directory: member and memberof properties relationship

Tags: active-directory

Modifying `member` attribute of a group in Active Directory (let's say with `asdiedit`), automatically modifies `memberOf` property of corresponding user?

And as secondary question, setting member in the `allowedAttributesEffective` of a group automatically adds the memberof in the `allowedAttributesEffective` attribute of all users?

I have no permission yet to modify `member` property, so I cannot test by myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, if you modify `member` attribute of a group.  It will automatically update the `memberOf` attribute.

`memberOf` attribute is called *computed back-link attribute* or *constructed attribute*.  It's maintained and calculated by Active Directory.  You cannot modify this attribute.

Similarly, `allowedAttributesEffective` is a *computed attribute*, reflecting the actual ACLs set on the AD object.  You cannot set this attribute directly but you can modify the ACLs on the AD object.  This attribute will reflect the fact.

There is no relationship between group's `allowedAttributesEffective` attribute and user's `allowedAttributesEffective`.  They are independent.  Setting ACL on group object won't affect the ACL on user object that the group contains.

Comment: Just for completeness, can I modify directly the memberOf attribute of a user? If yes, do I need to have the allowedAttributesEffective for user's memberof attribute and for group's member attribute to succeed?

Comment: @Eduard You cannot modify `memberOf` attribute.  It's computed by Active Directory instead.

Comment: @HarveyKwok i swear i've seen this on my enterprise system not be in sync with each other. where `memberOf` attribute on user did not agree with `member` attribute on the corresponding group. does this indicate a major system issue? or a possibly custom configuration with my enterprise system?

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza, not necessarily.  `memberOf` attribute is a _constructed_ attribute but group membership calculation in AD is complicated.  If the user is a member of domain local group from another domain within the same forest, `memberOf` attribute won't be able to show them.

Comment: why i can not find memberof attribute in user? but i can find member attribute in group, ActiveDirectory.

Comment: @acerphenix, probably cause the user is not a member of any group except the primary group